# Extract minutes and seconds from epoch

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am interested in way to extract time (hour, minutes, and seconds from epoch. So for example:

```
user_id     |  seconds   
------------+------------
      53115 | 1461224491
      53115 | 1461224492
      53115 | 1461224493
      53115 | 1461224494
      53115 | 1461224495
      53115 | 1461224496
      53115 | 1461224497
      53115 | 1461224498
      53115 | 1461224499
      53115 | 1461224500
```

To this:

```
 user_id    |  seconds   |        login_time        
------------+------------+------------------------
      53115 | 1461224491 |  08:41:31
      53115 | 1461224492 |  08:41:32
      53115 | 1461224493 |  08:41:33
      53115 | 1461224494 |  08:41:34
      53115 | 1461224495 |  08:41:35
      53115 | 1461224496 |  08:41:36
      53115 | 1461224497 |  08:41:37
      53115 | 1461224498 |  08:41:38
      53115 | 1461224499 |  08:41:39
      53115 | 1461224500 |  08:41:40
(10 rows)
```

Comment: Would be so much easier with a proper timestamp. https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a builtin function to cast Unixtime to Timestamp. Then cast to Time to remove the date part:

```
cast(to_timestamp(seconds) as time)
```

Comment: UNIX epoch "timestamps" do not account for time zones. But the conversion to a proper timestamp will. If the results always need to be viewed as posted you need to adjust the above to "select (to_timestamp(seconds) at time zone 'UTC-1')::time"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL use:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1461224491), '%H:%i:%s');
```

Comment: He tagged `postgresql`

Answer (score 0):

Date functions vary across different RDBMS, so read up on the postgresql date functions.

I once wrote a stored procedure for UNIX time (seconds since 1/1/1970 00:00:00 GMT) that started before 1970, the day after the preceding leap day.  I first took off the 4 year increments (4x365+1 days), then years (365 days) then months March through January using a string as an array of integers ("3130313031313031303131") so what days left (86400 seconds per) were February, and the remainder was time.  I forget how I adjust for time zone as well as getting back to March 1, 1968 00:00:00, something left to the student.  Having leap days at the end of a cycle means you can ignore them.  If February has 29 days left, so be it -- never a problem!

Those pesky seconds added in as the earth slows are left to astronomical clock fans!

Luckily, from 1970 to 2099, every 4 years has a leap day.  To go past 1901-2099, you need to worry about mod 100 being not leap but mod 400 being leap.